# how to set the tabs in the bottom of the screen in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-tabs

i am working on tabactivity.

i wanna show my tabwidget below the tabcontent(framelayout).

i done it by setting the tabwiget tab attribute as

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

but the framelayout cant align with those tabs.

**that is the tabs are shown at the bottom of the screen and overlap the framelayout**

how to do that? if set some height value to the framelayout it not optimized for all screens of android. what can i do? any idea???

Comment: Please spend a few seconds to search for existing questions. This same question was asked *yesterday*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom

Comment: I think Christopher's point was that if people couldn't answer the other guy's question, they probably wouldn't be able to answer yours either. In other words, there's no need to ask the question again, and instead you should try looking somewhere else.

Comment: As this question is a duplicate, I will simply link to my full answer on the other question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom/2710404#2710404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom/2710404#2710404)

Comment: examle code with tabs in the bottom of the screen:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23141213/2765497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or just use a custom one from:
http://code.google.com/p/androidtabs/

it allows tabs on the bottom

Answer (score 4):

The basic concept behind the `Tab-Activity` as follows

**`TabHost`** is a container for a tabbed window view. 
This object holds two children: a set of tab labels that the user clicks to select specific tab, and a FrameLayout object that displays the content of that page.

The individual element are typically controlled using this container object, rather then setting values on the child elements themselves.

**`TabWidget`** displays a list of tab labels representing each page in the parent's tab collection. The container object for this widget is TabHost. 
When a user selects a tab, this object sends a message to container, TabHost, to tell to switch the display page. The container TabHost is used to add labels, add the callback handler, and manage callbacks.

so adjust your layout as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-3dip"
        android:layout_weight="0" >
    </TabWidget>
  </LinearLayout>

  </TabHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Android's examples to the rescue!

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Just swap tabcontent and tabs in res/layout/main.xml:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />        
   <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: two thinks i have to tell u.

1. its not work unless u set the gravity for ur tabwidget.
2. when the framelayout content's height i larger than the screen height the tabwidget lose its visibility from ur screen.

please try ur example and let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Please Check the following link

There are two ways to display tabs at the bottom of a tab activity.

1) Using relative layout
 2) Using Layout_weight attribute

http://justkumar.blogspot.com/2011/09/tabs-at-bottom-of-tabactivity-by.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
android:id="@android:id/tabs">
</TabWidget>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**this is the code for bottom tab**

```
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
android:background="#0000"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
/>



  "android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```