# TabWidget not stable at the bottom in Android? Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

I set my tabWidget at the bottom. When i want to edit the edittext the keyboard will raise up. But the tab widget come above the keyboard. To support for the multiple screen i set the android:layout_weight="1.0". After that, I got this problem i added my layout code below. any idea to make the TabWidget at the bottom stably?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">

    </FrameLayout>
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:background="@drawable/gradient_black"
        android:listSelector="@color/transparent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6992662/593709) if you want iPhone like tab hosts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to adjust the [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) in your manifest.  This controls how the screen shifts when the soft keyboard is shown.  Perhaps you want to AdjustPan instead of the default adjustResize?  This [page](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) has more info on the various input modes.