# android tabwidget need help

Tags: iphone, android, tabwidget

i need to create tab in my application i've used the following working good... but i need it to display as tabs look into the iphone how it can possible it using android 1.6? thanks in advance..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i've tried this but my application crashes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
 <FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 >
 </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had customized android tab to look like iPhone UITabBar, found here:

- [Android - iphone style tabhost : my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992662/593709)
- [Android - iphone style tabhost : another good effort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14501478/593709)

OR you can implement your own tabs using `RadioGroup` but requires hell of work,
to implement `RadioGroup` you can refer to [this project](https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton). It uses Iphone like `SegmentedControl`, and you can use it by yourself to look like iphone tab.

Comment: First two links lead to nowhere now. First gives 404, second leads to description but link for code gives 404. Dead end.