# Aligning fonts in tabwidget

Tags: android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-tabactivity, android-fonts

[image]

Myself designing an app which uses GPS and Maps. I have created the UI as tabs. But i couldn't able to keep the font below the image.

Code in my Mainactivity

```
TabSpec gpsspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("GPS");
gpsspec.setIndicator("GPS", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gps));
Intent gpsIntent = new Intent(this, GpsActivity.class);
gpsspec.setContent(gpsIntent);
tabHost.addTab(gpsspec);
```

XML file in my drawable folder for tabs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gps_icon"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gps_icon" />
</selector>
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Kindly help in aligning the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide

- Small size of icons for small density devices in `drawable-ldpi` folder
- Medium size of icons for medium density devices in `drawable-mdpi` folder
- Large size icons for large density devices in `drawable-hdpi` folder

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources) is documentation guide for sizes of the drawable and layouts.

if it doesn't solve your problem, you can consider provding your own customized tab indicator, which I've used in [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992662/593709).