# Radically custom tabs in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am trying to create a rather radical tab redesign for my Android app. I want the tabs to be differently sized both in width and height, as well as having the focused tab have a shadow over the content as well as other tabs. However, I do not know how to change the height of tabs or the shadow cast by the focused tab. Can anyone help? Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You want change the default TabHost Style? or to implement this style.

Comment: Was that answer useful. Have you tried with that method?

Comment: I am still trying to figure it out. It seems to be helping, however. Don't worry, you'll get credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize your Tabhost with your custom style means, you've to customize it. For this case we can do with one feature -

1) Inflating the customized `xml` file to main `TabWidget's` using `LayoutInflater`

2) Do the changes whatever you need in your inflated xml file. For, this please refer below existing answer from stackoverflow. This will surely help you.

[Customized TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992662/940096)