# Custom Tabbar android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a custom tabbar for my android app like pic (tabbar on iphone)

[image]

and when i pass from tab to other it make a animation

Help pls

Comment: you can find demo [from this link](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/custom-tabbar-android/)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677698/android-iphone-style-tabhost