# make child of tabwidget bigger than tabwidget

Tags: android, tabwidget

I have 5 buttons on tab widget, 2 from left and 2 from right are the same size as background of tabwidget. The central button needs to be twice higher than tabwidget.

if I put all buttons into tabhost, tabhost's size rises equels to the biggest button (central button).
How to prevent it?

I want to make something like this. The background height of tabbar needs to be equel to red square's height.

[image: I want to make something like this]

Comment: Why don't you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6992662/940096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by following Xml code -

**center_tab_indicator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="65dip"    
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/center_tab_indicator"       
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:scaleType="center"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

**tab_indicator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="55dip"    
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" /> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
    />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

By use of above two XML You can get your desired output. For more, have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992662/940096)  You will get an out put like below -

[image]

Have a look at that. There will be sample project also available. Hope it helps you.