# In android how to create footer with three buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

Guys I need to make a footer with three buttons in such a way that left and right button should take 25%  of the screen from left and right and image which is in center should take the 50% of the screen without leaving any space between them.

It would be really great if anyone can help.

I wanted to post the image of the footer needed,but I am not allowed to share images.

Comment: You can use tabhost and set its position at bottom. Have a reference [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2677698/1050058). But it does not encourage to use bottom tab like iphone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="4" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="hello"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="2" android:text="hello"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: This is what I wanted ,I made some changes in your code,and it worked for me. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If you want custom bottombar in all activities then you need to include layout in all activities.
i think below code might help you :

1. Create bottomlayout.xml in layout derectory and copy below code inside it and use appropriate images.

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:background="@android:color:black"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/btn_1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:background="@drawable/img1" />

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/btn_2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:background="@drawable/img2" />

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/btn_3"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:background="@drawable/img3" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Include above xml in all activities at bottom like :

   < LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/bottombar"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:background="@android:color:black"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
3. Write Below code in all .Java files where you have include bottonlayout in .xml layout file.

   ```
   ImageButton btn1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
   ImageButton btn2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
   ImageButton btn3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_3);

   btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           // Your Code Here....
       }
   });

   btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           // Your Code Here....
       }
   });

   btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           // Your Code Here....
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Write layout XML as following.

```
 <LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4">
    <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25%"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="50%"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="25%"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Linear layout should placed in a relative layout to make it to align parent bottom.

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

So your final layout will be similar to following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
    <!-- Root element should wrap to parent size. -->

    <!-- Your view xml codes. -->

    <!--Bottom bar layout should be in root element. Parent should be Relative layout so that we can always align to parent bottom-->
    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="4">"
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25%"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="50%"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25%"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this fix your issue.

Comment: Guys thank u all for your answer. I am able to achieve what I wanted,But the problem is, the footer is not getting fixed at the bottom,its coming in the middle.