# Viewpager in Android with fixed tabs at bottom with Icon and Text in each tab

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabstrip

I want to create the following layout - an activity with a viewpager along with a tab that stays that the bottom of the activity to indicate which of the 4 fragments the user is in (and the selected tab gets highlighted by an 'active colour')

[image]

I've spent some time looking at various resources online to add this tab.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs - this looked like it would work well until I found out that `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` is deprecated

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528687/how-to-add-the-icon-for-swipeable-tabs) however, it is the same solution (i.e. deprecated)

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473213/action-bar-navigation-modes-are-deprecated-in-android-l) however, the PagerTitleStrip shows one tab (and partly the adjacent tabs) while I want to see all the tabs (there are no partially hidden tabs as in the picture)

Is there a tutorial that explains how to achieve this? It is one of the most basic UI elements, so I am hoping I am not finding the best solution

Comment: did you find a solution? I am looking as well

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same and I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547290/put-tabs-in-the-bottom-of-screen),
here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21547662/609782) OP says that

> it's against Android Design Guideline since at bottom there are soft/hard buttons like back button home button etc.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

But if you insist on to put them at the bottom, you can implement it like GitHub example consists tabs in bottom, using FragmentTabHost.

https://github.com/rameshkec85/BottomTabsFragmentTabHost

So even I am considering it.