# android tabhost custom color

Tags: android, android-style-tabhost

I am using Tabhost for project Tabs. I changed the color of the tab to blue but there is 2px line bellow the tab. Can any one help me to change the white color to blue.
http://img816.imageshack.us/img816/228/device.png

Comment: I am curious how you achieved this position, can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably something wrong with your screen design not related to TabHost. Did you check the screen/widgets/layouts paddings?

The following code snippet does exactly what you want. Add another Tab and that's it.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs">

            <include android:id="@+id/tab1" layout="@layout/tab1" />

            <include android:id="@+id/tab2" layout="@layout/tab2" />

            <include android:id="@+id/tab3" layout="@layout/tab3" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Hi the padding problem exist only in sdk 1.5. When i changed my coding to 1.6, the white border disappeared automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

I don't know if there is still no interface to customize or disable the bar below the tabs, but would be interested in an answer as well.