# TabWidget buttons

Tags: android, tabwidget

Is it possible to display tab buttons at bottom, rather than top? I need to port an application, which was originally designed on iPhone, where the default "tab" buttons are at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look [at this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom) which gives one known method to do this. However, I suppose that you can obtain an equivalent result by overriding some classes of the SDK.