# Android Tabs in Bottom of the Layout

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

How to add tabs at the bottom of the screen in android.Please any one tell the answer