# Is it possible Bottom Tabview like iphone in android?

Tags: android, uitabview

I need a tabview , but i has to be at bottom , am having a custom title , it covers most of topview . So i want to go v with bottom tab view . Other question is that , can i add Tabview in a tabview.

Thanking you ,

Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

While it is possible to have multiple levels of Tabs in a layout, you probably don't want to do this from a UX perspective and add other UI elements. :-)