# How to set tab bar at the bottom in android?

Tags: android, tabbar

I am using a tab bar in android.

By default, it displays at the top.

I want it to be displayed at the bottom.

Can someone please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please check this link: [How to align your TabHost at the bottom of the screen](http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom)

Adding **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** for the TabWidget does the trick.

Comment: Is it possible to use TabHost inside a ActionBarActivity?

Answer (score 5):

Just place content layout above tab widget.
See following link for more info.
[Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="1dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>>

</TabHost>
```