# placing tabs in bottom

Tags: android

hi i want place the tab widget in bottom of the screen i am using the below code .with that it displays in top can any one know the soution

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="bottom"/>
    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="bottom">  
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" 
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"

        />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Read full post related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom

Comment: Try for Scrollable TabHost.. http://code.google.com/p/mobyfactory-uiwidgets-android/ ....This is what you need i think..

Answer (score 0):

try this one....

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="80dip" 
             >
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#E0FFFF">
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have tried this but it displays tab in top .i need to be it in bottom