# Android tab layout placing tab at screen's buttom

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

I'd like to place the Tabs of tab layout in the buttom of the screen, iPhone like.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the below xml ... Now If you want to put your tabs to bottom just move your tabwidget below Framelayout (relativiely) as tabwidget and Framelayout are inside relative layout.

```
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:background="#00FFFF"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```