# How to make Tabhosts in the top and in the bottom?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I want to add multiple tab host in my application like this but on the bottom i want to have a tabhost

http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_41423120100516162056.png

Answer (score 0):

The top part appears to be a TabHost; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

The bottom part actually just looks like a Menu is open; http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

To place a TabHost at the bottom of the screen see this other answer, lots of upvotes for it; [Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Comment: thank you for your reply , I want the bottom part to be a tabhost

Comment: Added a third link to help with that.

Comment: the problem when i make them together , should i create a class that extends from TabActivity or a simple Activity

Comment: I would extend from Activity. Using TabActivity doesn't give you a great deal in terms of setup anyway. Be sure to call tabHost.setup() in your activity if you extend from Activity before you add any tabs to it though.