# Is possible in android to put in TabActivity tab icons at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Is possible in android to put in TabActivity tab icons at the bottom of the screen ? By default tab icon are at the top. How to change this ?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710404/181002

Have a nice day.

Comment: Check: http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom

Answer (score 1):

Create your Tab XML as `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

`

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work !