# Tabhost android with a fixed header

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/show_recipe_bg">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <Button 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/saveRecipeButtonId" 
                android:text="@string/save_recipe_button" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

I want the button to apear on the TOP for all tabs, a fixed header.
The problem in this layout that the TAB icons (TabWidget) do not apear on the screen. I guess that is because of the fill_parent for the frame layout. But I do not want to define a fixed size (because it is not good for using on other devices...)

How can I fix:
I need it to be like
Button
Tabs
TabWidget

EDIT:
I have found the problem, new XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/show_recipe_bg"> 

    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/saveRecipeButtonId" 
        android:text="@string/save_recipe_button" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TabHost 
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

how about this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/tabs"></TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab1"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab2"></LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tab3"></LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Hmmmmm didn't think about it - will try it. Thanks

Comment: Still not good - since the TABS are in the buttom of the screen - they disappear

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible ways:

1. It is mentioned in @sampathpremarathna answer - just move `Button` up in hierarchy, to the level of `TabHost`
2. You can try to change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and define that `FrameLayout` should be below button, and above tabs.

Comment: The problem is that the TAB icons are in the buttom of the layout. When using match_parent the frame of the tab takes the screen and the TABs are out of the screen

Comment: In second solution - in relative layout you can provide params `android.alignParentRight`, `android.alignParentLeft`, `android.above` and `android.below` there is no matter what you write in `width` or `height` params - it just ignored