# Android keyboard puts tab bar on top

Tags: android, keyboard, android-tabhost

I have a little problem when I open keyboard in my application. I have a tab bar which is on bottom of page and in some situations, not always when I click on edit text and keyboard shows up, it's moving my tab bar on top of it. Here is an example :

[image]

So my question is : Is there any way to disable this. I want my tab bar to stay hidden under keyboard when it shows up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

add these properties for your activity in manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @ Derzu, did you find solution for this... stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan doesn't work for me too..

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to tell the TabBar to adjust for Softkeyboard Mode. To do this, go to your manifest file, and in the Tabbar Activity add this line,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This makes your Tabbar to stay at the bottom even when the softkeyboard is visible.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

There is probably some confusion over this since it's currently missing from the documentation at

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft