# Setting TabHost layout parameters using java code?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am in a condition that my app needs TabHost using only java code not the xml . But i need the TabHost height to be set 20dp. Is that possible using only java code?

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. hope it may be helpful

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(index).getLayoutParams().height =(int) height;
```

Comment: Do you know how can i display this tabhhost at bottom of the screen..using only java!!

Comment: or check this. it ll help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom

Answer (score 3):

I think this can help you:

```
TabHost tabHost = new TabHost(context);
tabHost.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(YOUR_WIDTH_HERE, YOUR_HEIGHT_HERE));
```

You can use ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT or WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT

Comment: Then you have to change the LayoutParams class type from ViewGroup.LayoutParams to other class... if you pay attention to your classCastException, I think the error tell you what is the expected LayoutParams class..

Comment: can u tell me how can i display same tabhost at bottom of the screen using java?

Comment: the best approach is to put the tab host into a RelativeLayout and then do something like this: ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tabHost.getLayoutParams()).layout_alignParentBottom = true; - I didn't tried this code but it might help..

Comment: I am new to this can u please elaborate how to put the tabhost in layout?

Comment: I think you have to open a new question for this otherwise I can't help you more..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141019/how-to-set-a-tabhost-at-bottom-of-the-screen-using-only-java new question please help?

Answer (score 1):

For any view you can provide custom width and heiht by providing `LayoutParams`. All sizies in LayoutParams set in pixels. If you want to use `dp` - use this code:

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```