# How to set a tabHost at bottom of the screen using only java?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am working to create a TabHost at bottom of the screen using only java code.
I am in a condition that I cant use xml layouts .Can someone expert in dynamic layouts could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can do this by providing `alignParent` rule for parent `RelativeLayout`, if you have one.
- You can do this by providing correct order if your parent is `LinearLayout`
- **DO NOT use bottom tabs. Read [design guides](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) first.**