# Android Chat Screen sort issue

Tags: android

I am working on a chat aaplication.In which i have to chat window through which i am sending message.

!![For this image i am using sending message.You can see in this window i have a showall button if a person talking with no one that on show all button i have to show nothing but if a person is talking with 1,2 or more then i have to show winodw like image2 given below.][1]!

![In case of image 1 when user click on image 1 showall button if there is going chatting then i have to show image like that if more than one person is chatting then image2 will show list of chat winodow as in image1  if click any of them then chat related to that winodow will be open. ][2]

Comment: Don't expect someone else to write it for you.Just make a little research on Google how to use TabHost, RelativeLayout and the other elements which you need. You can find a lot of information for what you need : )

Comment: okay i want only just litle help not coding part i want.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said you need to check how to use TabHost in Android : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom) you can see how you can set TabHost in bottom of your page as in your attached screenshot.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) is another tutorial how to use TabHost with icons and etc.

Check `RelativeLayout` which you will need to set done button at the bottom of your page : [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html). About the chat views which are in your screenshot you can use `ViewFlow`
 to implement this kind of preview : [Android ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow).

Hope this information helps you. If you have any other questions, just ask : )

Comment: i am already used the tabhost for my app my app is working fine.the issue for my chat window..........

Comment: on my chat window chat part also working fine but i have to show on show all button click like the second image list of chatwindow in horizontal scrollview if any of these i click i have to show chat winodw of that with messages.........

Comment: As I said you can use ViewFlow for the preview and you can implement your own logic where after user click the chat you can open it in new activity or just load it the current one.