# Is it possible to have a two level action bar?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, fragment, slidingdrawer

I'm developing an Android app implementing the a tabhost, viewpager, and a top-side sliding drawer and tabs at the bottom. The application uses the android-support-v4 FragmentPagerAdapter, which can be found in the samples of the v4-support-package. A reference can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

I can't seem to get both the Sliding Drawer and the TabHost to appear on the screen at the same time.

Here is my layout.  The com.mobicartel... block is a custom sliding drawer. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mobicartel.tabsandpager"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.mobicartel.tabsandpager.slidingdrawer.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mobicartel.tabsandpager"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        my:direction="topToBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        my:handle="@+id/handle"
        my:content="@+id/content">
        <include
            android:id="@id/content"
            layout="@layout/pen_content" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40px"
            android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
    </com.mobicartel.tabsandpager.slidingdrawer.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>    

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_host_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/drawer">

    <TabHost    
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

          <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
</FrameLayout>
```

The content of TabHost actually isn't being displayed.  Instead, the tab listener & viewpager listener control each other so they are in sync.  The ViewPager is populated with fragments by a special adapter.

Any ideas?

Does anybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used TabHost with tabs at the bottom, because it is advised against (in the official Design Guidelines), however, it appears that you are using the hack found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710404/377260.

I notice that your `FrameLayout` weight is 0, along with the height and width. Try setting them to:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

as found in the answer linked to.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the frame layout was set to 0 dims because it actually was not supposed to be displayed.  The content is displayed in a view pager.  I'm following an iPhone design, so the tabs have to go on the bottom, but I will take the design guidelines into note for future projects.