# Want to create custom tab bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i am new to android and i want to create a custom tab bar with five tabs at bottom.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried ?https://www.google.co.in/search?q=custom+tab+bar+in+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Do not put a tab bar at the bottom. See "Don't use bottom tab bars" in the Android Design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: This example on github really helped me out when I was trying to learn how to create a custom tab bar.

https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android

Comment: @CommonsWare I know the guidelines say so, but in my opinion it depends on the app. If you got an action bar and something underneath that, it'd be awkward to have the tab bar on top. There are many existing Android apps with the tab bar in the bottom - so if the reason is to prevent confusion, I doubt users will be confused... I'm not gonna follow guidelines for the sake of following guidelines. If the guidelines told you to use Comic sans, would you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help: [align-tabhost-at-bottom](http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom)

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom) question. It also may be helpful.