# Best Layout Design of Bottom Tab Bar in HoneyComb Tablet App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to design Tab Bar at bottom in HoneyComb Tablet. So, is there any specific way or bar available to design layout for bottom tabbar?.

Comment: The "best way" is to not use bottom tab bars, as that runs counter to the Android design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: Ok, Is there any good demo or example available so I can look into it and see how its exactly working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use default TabHosts in Android and add the attribute

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the TabWidget

see links below for more info

1. [How to align your TabHost at the bottom of the screen](http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom)
2. [Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have seen TabWidget for device but in Tablet does it make any difference or is there any other way available to design?.

Comment: It will make no difference on tablet. You need to give the appropriate graphic for the Tab icons.

Comment: @Andy Like @M Mohsin Naeem said it will make no difference just use appropriate image for xhdpi resolution

Comment: @K_Anas I have tried with default TabWidget but can't see at bottom of tablet.

Answer (score 0):

To draw iphone type tab-bar

I generally Use TextView with Background Gardients in LinearLayout Horizontal.

TextView have drawable top property which can help to include icons.

I don't recommend default tab layout

```
public void setFooterStyle(Context c,TextView profile,TextView parking,TextView taxi,TextView history,TextView help,int flag)
{   
    if(flag==0)
    {
        profile.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_background_gradient);
        profile.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        profile.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.profile1, 0, 0);
    }
    else if(flag==1)
    {
        parking.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_background_gradient);
        parking.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }
    else if(flag==2)
    {
        taxi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_background_gradient);
        taxi.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        taxi.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.taxi_on, 0, 0);
    }
    else if(flag==3)
    {
        history.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_background_gradient);
        history.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        history.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.history_on, 0, 0);
    }
```

In your activity

```
Global.getInstance().setFooterStyle(getApplicationContext(),(TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnprofile),(TextView)findViewById(R.id.btnparking),(TextView)findViewById(R.id.btntaxi),(TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnhistory),(TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnhelp), 4);
```

Comment: So in that case we need to handle each activity.

Comment: You jsut need to write utility function that will handle activity state and pass this in your activity like this :