# FragmentTabHost bottom TabWidget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

Hello How I can create bottom TabWidget in FragmentTabHost ?
My xml looks line this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But my TabWidget is still at the top.

Comment: Note that bottom tabs go against the Android design aesthetic: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: I know but I need to create bottom tabbar with fragments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Tabs at the BOTTOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Comment: Not anymore. Google now has blessed tabs at the bottom of the screen!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I came up with this solution after six hrs effort on it..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:**

For implementing custom tabs:

```
mTabHost.addTab(setIndicator(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1"),
                        R.drawable.image1),

    public TabSpec setIndicator(Context ctx,TabSpec spec, int resid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.tabs_text, null);
        v.setBackgroundResource(resid);
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        text.setText(spec.getTag());
        return spec.setIndicator(v);
    }
```

Parameter resid as Drawable like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_compose_h" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_compose_h" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_compose"/>

</selector>
```

https://github.com/rameshkec85/BottomTabsFragmentTabHost

Comment: Nice work +1, can you please explain the behaviour?? where is `TabWidget` gone!!

Comment: In there, is FragmentTabHost just the tab bar and control the switch fragment??? if I want to set a background for the tab bar, just add android:background="@drawable/test" in the stction of android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost in xml??

Comment: How can i remove tabstrips using `FragmentTabHost`

Comment: @Ramesh Thanks. How can i change tab background color on click of tab?? Any idea

Comment: Works really well. But Im not sure what the second FrameLayout (the one inside FragmentTabHost) is for. The tabs work without it.

Answer (score 7):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/tabbar_bg"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```