# How to change selection color of tab host

Tags: android, tabs, android-widget

I want to change selection color of tab widget in my app. I Checked many answers & links but only able to change color of whole tab.

Following is what I want:

[image]

I want to change default blue selection color with green only. And not color of whole tab. What and how should i do in order to accomplish this ?

Edit :
Following way i'm creating tabs.

```
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"), ContactFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Favorite").setIndicator("Favorite"), FavoriteFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Group").setIndicator("Group"), GroupFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: You can use onTabChanged method

Comment: yes, but what to do in that method? That is what i'm not clear with.

Comment: if the current tab is selected one then change background color of that widget

Comment: @I-droid: you need to deal with 9patch background drawable instead of color.

Comment: @MehulJoisar :I am ready to use them. But how ? I have no idea about how to use those images. Do i have to use custom drawable with those images? If yes what should its item ?

Comment: @I-droid: I have mentioned an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an example, you can look into resources of android-sdk,

Suppose,

go to :

```
android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable and look at file
```

tab_bottom_right.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press_bar_right"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_bar_right"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus_bar_right"/>
```

you can find associated 9 patch drawables in different folders.(hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,etc)
Suppose, go to:

```
android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable-hdpi
```

and look for drawable named `tab_press_bar_right.9.png`

**EDIT :**

Have a look at following post : [set selector drawable to tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804287/fragmenttabhost-bottom-tabwidget/14853097#14853097)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, i got this. And i have used `tab_indicator_holo.xml` in my project with green 9-patched images. But where to specify this drawable ? I'm using `FragmentTabHost`.

Comment: @I-droid: post some code so that I can guide. you just need to add `tab_indicator_holo.xml` in your `drawable` directory and set it as background of each tab.

Comment: @I-droid: I have added reference of example post.

Comment: @MehulJosiar : Can you just explain `set it as background of each tab` ??? I mean, how to do this ?