# FragmentTabHost graphical layout doesn't render

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-support-library

The graphical layout for a simple android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost never renders in either Eclipse or Android Studio.
The Console error I get is consistently:
`Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null`

I'm using the most basic XML file:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

but the same error occurs.

I just wanted to add more views above or below the tab widget and frame layout.
I don't care so much about seeing the tab content; I just want to see *the rest of my layout* - **but the problem is that NO OTHER VIEWS are rendered when a** `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` **resides in the layout**.

I've read and tried to resolve the issue from the answer to this post:
[Android: Tabs at the bottom with FragmentTabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408709/android-tabs-at-the-bottom-with-fragmenttabhost)
but I don't think that that is my problem; I'm not looking to put a TabWidget on the bottom.

Every other one of my XML files opens perfectly.

The same problem occurs in Android Studio:
[image: Android Studio doesn't render this either]

Comment: Is that error logcat or console? If logcat, please post.

Comment: it is an error log: in eclipse:
(Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log)

Comment: FragmentTabHost will not show any content  as the content will be added dynamically. So no issues their. Should work when u add the tabs in the code and test it.

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: I opened a bug-report, please vote on it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78772

Answer (score 4):

I had the same rendering problem as well as compilation error. I fixed the problem by finding that I was not passing Fragment when i was creating Addtab. You must pass atleast one fragment on mTabHost.addTab. Below is the working code.

```java
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup(HomeActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home"), HomeFragment.class, null);
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("mysheets").setIndicator("MySheets"));
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("bookmarks").setIndicator("Bookmarks"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the error you've got (sorry, I'm really busy right now so can't spend more time checking) but in general it seems that the `FragmentTabHost` from the support libs doesn't care about the xml at all. See my previous answer to another question:

[FragmentTabHost with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598819/fragmenttabhost-with-horizontal-scroll/14870710#14870710)

Answer (score 1):

From Layout i am getting the same Error..so,I resolve that Problem by Code only...It's working fine..Please try this code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    /******************************************************************************************************************
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     *****************************************************************************************************************/
    public DetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager contains the layout as specified in your question
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager, container, false);

        // Initialise the tab-host
        FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        // Initialise this list somewhere with the content that should be displayed
        List<String> itemsToBeDisplayed;

        for (String subItem : itemsToBeDisplayed) {
            // Give along the name - you can use this to hand over an ID for example
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("TAB_ITEM_NAME", subItem);

            // Add a tab to the tabHost
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(subItem).setIndicator(subItem), YourContentFragment.class, b);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}



/********************************************************
This class contains the actual content of a single tab  
**********************************************************/
public class YourContentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getArguments();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("TAB_ITEM_NAME")) {
                String subItem = extras.getString("TAB_ITEM_NAME");
                // Do something with that string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If U need to put fragmented tabs at bottom of screen ... 
@fallow undermentioned --

Make your xml file like this ..

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <!--   <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  -->

         <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

        </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    </LinearLayout>
```

---

Now if your concern is opening several fragments with in single fragmented tabs  ...

@follow steps ::

1. Create a container fragment. This container fragment will be default for all of your's tabs content.
2. For every tab content replace fragment U need with this container.

For ex:- Just like you replace your bed with different bed sheets .. :)

Your container fragment class that will be used differently in different tabs ... "LearnContainerFragment.java "

```
    public class LearnContainerFragment extends BaseContainerFragment {

        private boolean mIsViewInited;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.e("test", "tab 1 oncreateview");
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fragment, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Log.e("test", "tab 1 container on activity created");
            if (!mIsViewInited) {
                mIsViewInited = true;
                initView();
            }
        }

        private void initView() {
            Log.e("test", "tab 1 init view");
            replaceFragment(new Learn(), false);
        }

    }
```

LearnContainerFragment.java --- > it's xml file container_fragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container_framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </FrameLayout>
```

@ How to use Conatiner..

1. For every fragment U need will be replaced with id of this container fragment.

@last your BaseContainerFragment.java class --

```
public class BaseContainerFragment extends Fragment {

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    public boolean popFragment() {
        Log.e("test", "pop fragment: " + getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        boolean isPop = false;
        if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            isPop = true;
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        return isPop;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps..... 
 Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

not sure.... but shouldn't your layout have a tabhost tag in it above the tabwidget's linear layout?

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
>
```

i made an app a while back that implented tabs using tabhost and this is how my layout was...one tab had a calendar view one had an image switcher and one had a listview...sorry i can't be of more help

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageSwitcher
                    android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="251dp" >
                </ImageSwitcher>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <CalendarView
                    android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Well, a regular android.widget.TabHost would work, except that [android.app.TabActivity is deprecated][tabactivity] in favor of using FragmentTabHosts and Fragments.  [tabactivity]:[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html]