# Android Fragment Tab host, Tab text on two line. I would like it go have a horizontal scroll.

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

Good morning Or afternoon.

I am trying to add a page with tabs in this app. Currently this app is divided into `Fragments` with the top and bottom title bars in the activity.

This was fine for the rest of the app. Now I need to add a tab with both the bottom and top bars.

I have used JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator which worked perfect without the added navigation bars. But before the way the code was setup (before i came to the project) makes it Incredibly difficult to do this.

Not a problem I heard about Fragment Tab Host. So I got the fragment Tab Host working.

The problem with four tabs the text get squashed and wraps onto two line. I have searched may possible fixes including [FragmentTabHost with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598819/fragmenttabhost-with-horizontal-scroll)

However no matter what I try it just never seems to work.

Below is my Fragment

```
public class BPInformationFragment extends Fragment   {
private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
private View v;



private OnRightMenuClickedListener mCallback;


public static BPInformationFragment newInstance() { 
    BPInformationFragment f = new BPInformationFragment();

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnRightMenuClickedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnRightMenuClickedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(false);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_information, container, false);

    tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity()); tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),R.layout.layout_information);

        Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
    arg1.putInt("Frag", 1);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Symptomsn Long title"),
            InformationSymptomsFragment.class, null);



    Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
    arg2.putInt("Frag1", 2);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("StratagiesVerylong title"),
            InformationStrategiesFragment.class, arg2);

    Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
    arg3.putInt("Frag2", 3);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("B-Safe"),
        BPAboutFragment.class, arg3);

    Bundle arg4 = new Bundle();
    arg4.putInt("Frag3", 4);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("Radar"),
        BPMyAccountFragment.class, arg4);

    TabWidget tw = (TabWidget)v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tw.getParent();
    HorizontalScrollView hs = new HorizontalScrollView(getActivity());
    hs.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.addView(hs, 0);
    ll.removeView(tw);
    hs.addView(tw);
    hs.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    mCallback.setBottomButtons(DefinedConstants.MENU_INFORMATION);

    return tabHost;
}
```

Below is my XML

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone could help that would be amazing. Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your TabWidget between HorizontalScrollView.

Like this...

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it does not work `HorizontalScrollView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout`. I have tried this before. I have also tried solving the linearlayout. Once the cast exception is solved. nothing changes and the tabs are still on two line and not in a horizontal scroll view