# FragmentTabHost Horizontal Scrollview + Swipe Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

I viewed the following question

[FragmentTabHost with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598819/fragmenttabhost-with-horizontal-scroll)  and still was unable to get scrollable horizontal tabs in android. All the tabs stick to each other.

The *onCreateView* method of my fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

    tabHost.setup(getActivity(),getFragmentManager()/* getChildFragmentManager()*/, R.layout.fragment_home);

    Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
    arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Latest Videos"), HomeFragmentChild1.class, arg1);

    Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
    arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Hot Videos"), HomeFragmentChild2.class, arg2);

    Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
    arg3.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 3);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("My Videos"), HomeFragmentChild2.class, arg3);

    Bundle arg4 = new Bundle();
    arg4.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 4);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("Videos"), HomeFragmentChild2.class, arg4);

    Bundle arg5 = new Bundle();
    arg5.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 5);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab5").setIndicator("Sample Videos"), HomeFragmentChild2.class, arg5);

    TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tw.getParent();
    HorizontalScrollView hs = new HorizontalScrollView(this.getActivity());
    hs.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.addView(hs, 0);
    ll.removeView(tw);
    hs.addView(tw);
    hs.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    return tabHost;
}
```

XML :

```
<android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost                                                                               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"a
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>

 </android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Additionally, would it be possible to achieve a way to **swipe and change the tab** ?
Possible errors at my end?? Would be of great help ! Thanks!

Comment: Place your LinearLayout into HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: no, it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Using ViewPager would be a solution.

Please check this link: [Using ViewPager for Screen Slide](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Also see : [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)