# FragmentTabHost with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, fragment-tab-host

I'm trying to add HorizontalScrollView to FragmentTabHost. I was following 'Lore Giver' answer from [FragmentTabHost with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598819/fragmenttabhost-with-horizontal-scroll)
but its not working for me. 
After implementing xml like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabHostContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

And setting it up like this :

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.home_tabs, container, false)
    viewContext = view.context
    tabHost = view.findViewById(R.id.tabHost)
    tabHost.setup(view.context, fragmentManager, R.id.tabHostContent)
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(context!!.getString(R.string.TAB_EMERGENCY)), EmergencyFragment::class.java, null)
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("friends").setIndicator(context.getString(R.string.TAB_PRIVATE)), PrivateFragment::class.java, null)
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("organizations").setIndicator(context!!.getString(R.string.ORGANIZATIONS)), OrganizationsFragment::class.java, null)
    tabHost.tabWidget.dividerDrawable = null
    tabHost.tabWidget.isStripEnabled = false
    changeStyleOfSelectedTab()
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener {
        changeStyleOfSelectedTab()
        (activity as MainActivity).tabChangedByClick(currentTab)
    }
    return view
}
```

my tabs were not scrolling horrizontaly. The last Title ("Organizations") has just wrapped itself (it was not fitting on screen). 
After adding

```
tabHost.tabWidget.getChildAt(i).findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.title).setSingleLine(true)
```

for each of the tabs, organization TITLE started scrolling inside its tab. What am I doing wrong ?

[Bar after adding setSingleLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM6Yo.png)

Comment: this is marquee effect, try to change TextView's ellipsize property other than marquee

Comment: After adding `tv.ellipsize = null` the word "Organization" is just cut on the side of the screen (i see "organizatio" and part of "n" :) ). Scrolling still doesn't work.

Comment: set its width to wrap_content

Comment: you should follow the way of right answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598819/fragmenttabhost-with-horizontal-scroll

Comment: accepted answer together with my changes worked :) thanks

Comment: great...........