# FragmentTabHost: No tab known for tag null

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting this exception in the designer:

```
Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null
```

I have the same EXACT code as this guy -
[Android FragmentTabHost : No tab known for tag null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354165/android-fragmenttabhost-no-tab-known-for-tag-null)

his only answer was "use an older deprecated class" - TabHost instead of FragmentTabHost which is the one that I understood you need to use instead of...

I am a beginner to Android and to Java, but i've been a programmer for many years in .NET, and i find it really hard to find good solutions to very basic problems that came from apparently the only 3 tutorials for fragments out there (just like the one stated above)

So basically here are my questions so far:

1. From what i understood so far, the only way to actually make a menu to your Android application is to make it a single Activity app with fragments, if this is true, how should i keep track of my fragments if FragmentTagHost is not fully working yet? I found references for ActionBarSherlock - his latest version is using a lot of deprecated classes too
2. What are the best practices with using a single activity + fragments, and where can i find good helpful examples to get me going to achieve the ui i want to make?
3. Are there other third party solutions that can help along like ActionBarSherlock?
4. I am using the Eclipse ADT, would you recommend a different IDE?

Thanks a lot

PS - please don't refer me to the android developer tutorials, i've been thru them, and they are like learning the abc's while i need to make sentences and trying to find good sources for that, i am saying that because i found plenty of good questions on here that were just answered with "here is the really basic tutorial, go do that"

Comment: Your question is offtopic for stackoverflow as you ask for discussion/polling. You may want to come with something more specific with which you have problems.

Comment: "Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null" is a problem, with no answer
I asked a few follow up questions because i found no solution for that problem yet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370745/fragmenttabhost-graphical-layout-doesnt-render

Answer (score 0):

Find AndroidApiDemos project in the samples folder of SDK http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

There you can find FragmentTabs demo which is what you need, i assume

As for 3. Yes, there are a lot of different solutions. Previously in PlayStore was a good app with different UI patterns and links to the opensource projects implementing them com.groidify.uipatterns. Hope you can find it via google somewhere such as now it is not available

Comment: the problematic code that you can see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354165/android-fragmenttabhost-no-tab-known-for-tag-null was taken from the FragmentTabs demo

Comment: actually FragmentTabs demo uses actionbar tabs without xml layout, so it is not from there

Comment: also you can use the demo from ABS library https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java