# Android FragmentTabHost : Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

The graphical layout for a simple android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost never renders . I download example from this http://getquery.com/android-fragment-tab-example/ . It getting same error .

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

It display error in design "Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null"

How can I resolve that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16332068/1935890

Comment: I realize that can run application with out error

Comment: I opened a bug-report, please vote on it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78772