# iOS like Navigation Tab in Android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

As far as my project specification, I have to create iPhone like Navigation Tab and the application have to ran in lower device. In order to use ActionBar in 2.3 or lower device. I have to use `ActionBarSherlock`. Here is my code for the action bar

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.abstracts_show);



}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
```

I didn't use this library before.Now, how can I create tabs like in the picture with actionbersherlock ?  Now, so that I can switch my 4 classes via tab. I will be glad If you give any code sample or guideline.

[image]

Comment: You can use TabWidget in the folowing [way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You can use support library v7 and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar).