# Android - Tabs in bottom of screen

Tags: android, layout, tabs

I have been looking for about a day for a way to get my android application have tabs in the bottom of the screen.

On the Android Developer website in the Styles and Themes section, they seem to have the exact example of what I am trying to do, however they did not find it necessary to provide a decent example of this:

[image]

All the tips/solutions I find on the web are failing. I always seem to get the following butt-ugly layout where the tabs are very misplaced in the top of the screen next to the application name :-(

[image]

Does anyone have a clue how to accomplish this ?

Thank you so much in advance for any tips !

Comment: That are no tabs but a split ActionBar. You can read more about it in the Android Developer Guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Comment: @Wesley, This is a `Split Action Bar` view functionality. You can find some good example. You need to define attribute in `Android Manifest`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think these examples will be useful to you:  [Android Bottom tab bar example](http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom) AND [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the two link of github that has implemented tab at bottom.

[image]

https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android

[image]

https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Raised-Center-Tab-in-Android

Answer (score 2):

I use this layout for locate Tabs in bottom of screen:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_main_app_gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:background="#EAE7E1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

examle of code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23150258/2765497

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not search enough for your problem because you are searching using the wrong keyword.

What you are showing in 1st image at bottom of gmail app there are 4 menu and 5th overflow menu and upper at top action bar

You can place a menu at the bottom using a simple property in the manifest; one single line on main activity which showing action bar

`android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`

Like this :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.HomeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google does not recommend to have Tabs at the bottom.

See the following official design pattern guide from Android,
And look for the section **"Don't use bottom tab bars"**

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: no, while this is recommended by Android / Google, this sounds really ridiculous to layout designers. Using tabs is not really bad after all.

Comment: The latest Google+ app has tabs at the bottom of the screen, exactly in the way the doc says it shouldn't be used.

Comment: http://www.theverge.com/2016/3/15/11236152/material-design-update-bottom-navigation-bar

Comment: Latest Google apps like **Photo** , **Google+** use buttom navigation

Comment: The section you're talking about looks like it has been removed from the page.

Comment: Previously Android Docs recommended "Not to use Bottom Tabs", but now they have improved layout design patterns and have started implementing BottomTabs in Google+ app...

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post an update here. [Bottom nav bars are now Android Canon.](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-style) The main take-aways from this are:

1) Use bottom nav bars only for 3-5 icons. Any less, use [tabs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html). Any more, use scrollable tabs (page down on that same link).

2) Avoid using a bottom nav bar and tabs together, and be sure the responsibilities of both are clearly separated if you do.

3) Bottom nav bars should be used for *navigation* not *actions* (use the `ActionBar` for those)

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of **Bottom navigation**.

https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html

You can do this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033640/6207502

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple....

For simple tab bar we use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

But in Bottom Tab bar we use

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>**
```

The main thing is

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom=”true”;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question seeking to do the same thing, however according to androids development guidelines, you should not ever have a tab bar at the bottom, since this is an iOS feature...

[Android Development Standards](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

Comment: The funny this is that their own Gmail app used to have menus on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the bottom bar a bit confused. That's not a tab bar. The bottom bar is for actions, not navigating screens. For example, in the screenshot of the Gmail app you posted above, the bottom bar allows the user to: Compose Email, Search, Tag, Refresh and More. Refer: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Technically these buttons do navigate the user to other screens but, the tab bar is usually used to "switch" screens. For example viewing content by category.

Hmm, but in the latest version of the Gmail app they have these action buttons on top. Sigh...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The link is for reference only.