# Android new Bottom Navigation bar or BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Saw the new guideline came out, and used in `google photos` latest app.
Have no idea how to use the new Bottom Navigation Bar.
See through the new support lib, didn't find any lead.

[image]

Can not find any official sample.

How to use the new Bottom bar? Don't want to do any customize.

Comment: visit this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019986/which-view-should-be-used-for-new-material-design-bottom-navigation/42119958#42119958

Comment: You can take a look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967021/2412582

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031168/2468324

Answer (score 187, accepted):

**I think you might looking for this.**

**Here's a quick snippet to get started:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomBar mBottomBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Notice how you don't use the setContentView method here! Just
        // pass your layout to bottom bar, it will be taken care of.
        // Everything will be just like you're used to.
        mBottomBar = BottomBar.bind(this, R.layout.activity_main,
                savedInstanceState);

        mBottomBar.setItems(
                new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_recents, "Recents"),
                new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_favorites, "Favorites"),
                new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_nearby, "Nearby"),
                new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_friends, "Friends")
        );

        mBottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(final int position) {
                // the user selected a new tab
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

**Here is reference link.**

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

**EDIT New Releases.**

The Bottom Navigation View has been in the material design guidelines for some time, but it hasn’t been easy for us to implement it into our apps. Some applications have built their own solutions, whilst others have relied on third-party open-source libraries to get the job done. Now the design support library is seeing the addition of this bottom navigation bar, let’s take a dive into how we can use it!

> How to use ?

To begin with we need to update our dependency!

```
compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.0.0’
```

> Design xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content Container -->

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Create menu as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_schedules"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_music"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

> Handling Enabled / Disabled states. Make selector file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_checked="true"
      android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
  <item
      android:state_checked="false"
      android:color="@color/grey" />
 </selector>
```

> Handle click events.

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favorites:
                        
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_schedules:
                    
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_music:
                    
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
});
```

Edit : **Using Androidx you just need to add below dependencies.**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

If you want to read more about it's methods and how it works [read this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView)

**Surely it will help you.**

Comment: the bottom bar in the sample still customize by your self, any way to use origin android lib. I thought it might in the support lib. Or not public yet?

Comment: @zjywill It's not customized but it is way to use of official bottom navigation bar functionality in our app. Just try this code.

Comment: I would not suggest you to use roughhike bottom bar since the API isn't fully implemented and I've encountered rendering problems.
You cannot change the Icon at runtime, and it kept ignoring the colors i've set for the buttons background.

Comment: Please answer that how can I save history

Comment: Is there any way to disable the "zoom" effect when selecting one of the bottom bar items? I want the text and icon to be the same size all the time, regardless of which item is selected.

Comment: Scrolling behavior is really broken, too. Plus you can't enable titles when you have more than 3 items without losing the color transition feature.

Comment: @user2966445 according to google's design guideline the bottom bar icons and textview should be zoom out when they are touched. Reference : https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-style

Comment: @0101100101 If there are more than three tabs then the titles in the bottom bar should not be displayed according to the google's design guide. They should be visible when the respective tab is touched. Reference : https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-style

Comment: @SENTHILKUMARS Actually, the library allows it now and works much better than before. They're just guidelines anyway and IMO, that part is plain stupid. There are way too many people (or DAUs) who wouldn't understand the bottom bar without titles.

Comment: Hi @0101100101 Now I am also in need of displaying titles permanently for a bottom bar with four tabs :). As you said anyway it is just a guideline and IMO people need that.. You said now the library actually allows it right. Could you please give me that line of code so that it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: @SENTHILKUMARS Last time I tried with version 2.0, I just *didn't* add `app:bb_behavior="shifting"` and it worked.

Comment: My first tab constantly - gets selected any ideas why?

Comment: @SENTHILKUMARS I stand corrected. To get your app featured on the play store, a bar with 4 or 5 tabs must not show titles for inactive ones :'(

Comment: @jaydroider for 4 or more icons, its showing some animations. how can I remove that ?

Comment: @NabeelK Check my updated answer you will get idea to remove animation.

Comment: is there any way to draw badge on BottomNavigationItem using support library?

Comment: The java reflection on mShiftingMode helped me! I don't know what are they thinking by not expose this field

Comment: @jaydroider please provide referrer to original answer "How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?" for section "To remove animation or shift mode" as exact that part of your answer is copied from there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode

Comment: For some reason, my OnNavigationItemSelectedListener never gets called when I select a tab. Did anyone face the same problem?

Comment: roughike is deprecated now

Comment: @476rick Thanks for pointing it out but might you haven't read the full answer. roughike/BottomBar  was the answer before official *Bottom Navigation View* released. Then if you read the full answer you will find EDIT New Releases and you will find full implementation for official  *Bottom Navigation View* release.

Comment: Use `state-checked` instead of `state-enabled`. [For more info](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/)

Answer (score 49):

You should use [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) from v25 Android Support Library.
It represents a standard bottom navigation bar for application.

Here is a post on Medium that has a **step by step guide:**
https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0#.9vmiekxze

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153888/bottomnavigationview-not-showing-in-my-activity  hello maxim.. i implemented this, but its not showing up..

Comment: @SagarChavada you may want to look in this [post](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0#.9vmiekxze)

Comment: @DroidDev that is because the BottomNavigationView was released the day this answer was posted. Prior to that only third party solutions were available.

Comment: Do you know if you can do custom views with an adapter to it?

Comment: @MaximTuraev Will BottomNavigationView work for apps that have a minSDKVersion of 14 even though the target is 25?

Comment: @Alan, looks like BottomNavigationView is a part of Support Library which has min supported API level 9, so i guess it will work. You can still check it on emulator to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 24):

*My original answer dealt with the [`BottomNavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView), but now there is a [`BottomAppBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView). I added a section at the top for that with an implementation link.*

## Bottom App Bar

The `BottomAppBar` supports a Floating Action Button.

[image]

Image from [here](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-menu-and-navigation-c4f069e579ec). See the [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/) and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708) for help setting up the `BottomAppBar`.

## Bottom Navigation View

The following full example shows how to make a Bottom Navigation View similar to the image in the question. See also [Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/) in the documentation.

[image]

#### Add the design support library

Add this line to your app's *build.grade* file next to the other support library things.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Replace the version number with whatever is current.

#### Create the Activity layout

The only special thing we have added to the layout is the `BottomNavigationView`. To change the color of the icon and text when it is clicked, you can use a `selector` instead of specifying the color directly. This is omitted for simplicity here.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that we used `layout_alignParentBottom` to actually put it at the bottom.

#### Define the menu items

The xml above for Bottom Navigation View referred to `bottom_nav_menu`. This is what defines each item in our view. We will make it now. All you have to do is [add a menu resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50225618/3681880) just like you would for an Action Bar or Toolbar.

*bottom_nav_menu.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_recents"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_recents"
        android:title="Recents"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_favorites"
        android:title="Favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_nearby"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_nearby"
        android:title="Nearby"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

You will need to add the appropriate icons to your project. This is not very difficult if you go to **File > New > Image Asset** and choose **Action Bar and Tab Icons** as the Icon Type.

#### Add an item selected listener

There is nothing special happening here. We just add a listener to the Bottom Navigation Bar in our Activity's `onCreate` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_recents:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recents", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_favorites:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_nearby:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nearby", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Need more help?

I learned how to do this watching the following YouTube video. The computer voice is a little strange, but the demonstration is very clear.

- [Android Studio Tutorial - Bottom Navigation View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcE7IIHKfRg)

Answer (score 16):

You can also use Tab Layout with custom tab view to achieve this.

**custom_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_recents_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    private int[] mTabsIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_recents_selector,
            R.drawable.ic_favorite_selector,
            R.drawable.ic_place_selector};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Setup the viewPager
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }

        mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
    }


    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

        private final String[] mTabsTitle = {"Recents", "Favorites", "Nearby"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public View getTabView(int position) {
            // Given you have a custom layout in `res/layout/custom_tab.xml` with a TextView and ImageView
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(mTabsTitle[position]);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(mTabsIcons[position]);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {

                case 0:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(1);

                case 1:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(2);
                case 2:
                    return PageFragment.newInstance(3);

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mTabsTitle[position];
        }
    }

}
```

[Download Complete Sample Project](https://github.com/waleedsarwar86/BottomNavigationDemo)

Comment: According to Google design guidelines, one should not use a swiping motion to switch between tabs. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-style

Comment: Would be great if you put a credit for the author that wrote the behaviors :)

Answer (score 13):

Google has launched the BottomNavigationView after the version 25.0.0 of the design support library. But it came with the following limitations:

1. **You can't remove titles and center icon.**
2. **You cant't change titles text size.**
3. **Y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶a̶c̶k̶g̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶o̶r̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶l̶w̶a̶y̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶o̶r̶P̶r̶i̶m̶a̶r̶y̶.̶**
4. **It doesn't have a BottomNavigationBehavior: so no integration with FAB or SnackBar through CordinatorLayout.**
5. **Every menuItem is a pure extension of FrameLayout so it doesn't have any nice circle reveal effect**

So the max you can do with this fist version of BottomNavigationView is: (without any reflection or implementing the lib by yourself).

[image]

So, If you want any of these. You can use a third part library like [roughike/BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) or implement the lib by yourself.

Comment: Just for the record, you can change background color and you can change title text size (tho I have found other problems with the method I'm using). using android:background="xxx" will change its background color, but if you also specify a `app:itemBackground="xxx"` all the items share this color and you can't see the background (unless you add transparency, but still, all icons share the same color). Very lame that the Android team released such a crappy component… always 75% complete, missing the extra mile that would make it great.

Comment: we can change the background color

Comment: hi, I am using same lib and its working fine but here i want to display only icons without titles in center of bottom bar. is it possible? and i already tried to put empty in menu items but still icons are showing in top only. how can i show only icons without titles in center of Bottom bar?

Comment: hi, please check my answer for this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183239/remove-bottomnavigationview-labels/40188794#40188794

Comment: @MartinMarconcini How did you change the text size for the bottom navigation view?

Answer (score 11):

As Sanf0rd mentioned, Google launched the *BottomNavigationView* as **part of the Design Support Library version 25.0.0**. The limitations he mentioned are mostly true, except that you CAN change the background color of the view and even the text color and icon tint color. It also has an animation when you add more than 4 items (sadly it cannot be enabled or disabled manually).

**I wrote a detailed tutorial about it with examples and an accompanying repository, which you can read here:**
https://blog.autsoft.hu/now-you-can-use-the-bottom-navigation-view-in-the-design-support-library/

---

### The gist of it

You have to add these in your app level `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

You can include it in your layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView  
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/darkGrey"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />
```

You can specify the items via a menu resource like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<menu  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_one"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        android:title="One"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_two"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:title="Two"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_three"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:title="Three"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_four"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_reminder"
        android:title="Four"/>
</menu>
```

And you can set the tint and text color as a color list, so the currently selected item is highlighted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item
        android:color="@android:color/white"
        android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>
```

Finally, you can handle the selection of the items with an OnNavigationItemSelectedListener:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {  
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_one:
                // Switch to page one
                break;
            case R.id.action_two:
                // Switch to page two
                break;
            case R.id.action_three:
                // Switch to page three
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Suggestion - remove app:itemBackground="@color/darkGrey" to achive native circular ripple effect.

Answer (score 8):

Other alternate library you can try :- https://github.com/Ashok-Varma/BottomNavigation

```
<com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationBar = (BottomNavigationBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);

bottomNavigationBar
                .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.ic_home_white_24dp, "Home"))
                .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.ic_book_white_24dp, "Books"))
                .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.ic_music_note_white_24dp, "Music"))
                .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.ic_tv_white_24dp, "Movies & TV"))
                .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.ic_videogame_asset_white_24dp, "Games"))
                .initialise();
```

Comment: One other similar library is AHBottomNavigation: https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

Answer (score 4):

i've made a private class which uses a gridview and a menu resource:

```
private class BottomBar {

    private GridView mGridView;
    private Menu     mMenu;
    private BottomBarAdapter mBottomBarAdapter;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

    public BottomBar (@IdRes int gridviewId, @MenuRes int menuRes,View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(gridviewId);
        this.mMenu = getMenu(menuRes);
        this.mOnClickListener = onClickListener;

        this.mBottomBarAdapter = new BottomBarAdapter();
        this.mGridView.setAdapter(mBottomBarAdapter);
    }

    private Menu getMenu(@MenuRes int menuId) {
        PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this,null);
        Menu menu = p.getMenu();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(menuId,menu);
        return menu;
    }

    public GridView getGridView(){
        return mGridView;
    }

    public void show() {
        mGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mGridView.animate().translationY(0);
    }

    public void hide() {
        mGridView.animate().translationY(mGridView.getHeight());
    }



    private class BottomBarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater    mInflater;

        public BottomBarAdapter(){
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mMenu.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mMenu.getItem(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            MenuItem item = (MenuItem) getItem(i);

            if (view==null){
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout,null);
                view.setId(item.getItemId());
            }

            view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            view.findViewById(R.id.bottomnav_icon).setBackground(item.getIcon());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomnav_label)).setText(item.getTitle());

            return view;
        }
    }
```

your_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_item1"
        android:title="@string/title_item1"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/item2_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_item2"
        android:title="@string/title_item2"/>
    ...
</menu>
```

and a custom layout item your_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/bottomnav_icon"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/bottomnav_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        style="@style/mystyle_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

usage inside your mainactivity:

```
BottomBar bottomBar = new BottomBar(R.id.YourGridView,R.menu.your_menu, mOnClickListener);
```

and

```
private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.item1_id:
                //todo item1
                break;
            case R.id.item2_id:
                //todo item2
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

and in layout_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    ...
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <GridView android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/your_background_color"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fragment_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is also be useful.

**Snippet**

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, BottomNavigationBar.Listeners.IOnTabSelectedListener
{
    private BottomBar _bottomBar;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainActivity);

        _bottomBar = BottomBar.Attach(this, bundle);
        _bottomBar.SetItems(
            new BottomBarTab(Resource.Drawable.ic_recents, "Recents"),
            new BottomBarTab(Resource.Drawable.ic_favorites, "Favorites"),
            new BottomBarTab(Resource.Drawable.ic_nearby, "Nearby")
        );
        _bottomBar.SetOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        _bottomBar.HideShadow();
        _bottomBar.UseDarkTheme(true);
        _bottomBar.SetTypeFace("Roboto-Regular.ttf");

        var badge = _bottomBar.MakeBadgeForTabAt(1, Color.ParseColor("#f02d4c"), 1);
        badge.AutoShowAfterUnSelection = true;
    }

    public void OnItemSelected(int position)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
        // lose the current tab on orientation change.
        _bottomBar.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

**Links**

https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar

It's https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar ported to C# for Xamarin developers

Answer (score 3):

There is a new official **BottomNavigationView** in version 25 of the Design Support Library

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html
add in gradle
`compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'`

XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android.support.design"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    design:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This library, [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx), extends Google's BottomNavigationView. You can easily customise Google's library to have bottom navigation bar the way you want it to be. You can disable the shifting mode, change visibility of the icons and texts and so much more. Definitely try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have referred this [github post](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) and I have set the `three layouts` for `three fragment` pages in bottom tab bar.

**FourButtonsActivity.java:**

```
bottomBar.setFragmentItems(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fragmentContainer,
            new BottomBarFragment(LibraryFragment.newInstance(R.layout.library_fragment_layout), R.drawable.ic_update_white_24dp, "Recents"),
            new BottomBarFragment(PhotoEffectFragment.newInstance(R.layout.photo_effect_fragment), R.drawable.ic_local_dining_white_24dp, "Food"),
            new BottomBarFragment(VideoFragment.newInstance(R.layout.video_layout), R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp, "Favorites")

    );
```

**To set the badge count :**

```
  BottomBarBadge unreadMessages = bottomBar.makeBadgeForTabAt(1, "#E91E63", 4);
  unreadMessages.show();
  unreadMessages.setCount(4);
  unreadMessages.setAnimationDuration(200);
  unreadMessages.setAutoShowAfterUnSelection(true);
```

**LibraryFragment.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String STARTING_TEXT = "Four Buttons Bottom Navigation";

    public LibraryFragment() {
    }

    public static LibraryFragment newInstance(int resource) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(STARTING_TEXT, resource);

        LibraryFragment sampleFragment = new LibraryFragment();
        sampleFragment.setArguments(args);

        return sampleFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                getArguments().getInt(STARTING_TEXT), null);
        return view;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

navigation.xml(inside menu)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

Inside `onCreate()` method,

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
//Dont forgot this line     
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);
```

And Create class as below.

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the layouts according to the above-mentioned answers 
If anyone wants to use this in kotlin:-

```
 private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.images -> {
          // do your work....
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
       R.id.videos ->
         {
          // do your work....
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}
```

then in oncreate you can set the above listener to your view

```
   mDataBinding?.navigation?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
```