# Change background color Bottom Bar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, bottombar

I have a problem in my Android project. 
I can't change the color of the bottombar. 
This is how I want my bottombar to look:
[image: wanted Like this]

**This is my code**

**menu > tabhost_bottom.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>
<item
    android:id="@+id/home_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:title="Home"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/setting_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:title="Setting" />
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabhost_activity);

    BottomBar bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.tabhost_bottom, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {

        }
    });

    // Set the color for the active tab. Ignored on mobile when there are more than three tabs.
    bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#55a8e5");

    // Use the dark theme. Ignored on mobile when there are more than three tabs.
    bottomBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55a8e5"));
    // Use custom text appearance in tab titles.
    //bottomBar.setTextAppearance(R.style.MyTextAppearance);

    // Use custom typeface that's located at the "/src/main/assets" directory. If using with
    // custom text appearance, set the text appearance first.
    //bottomBar.setTypeFace("MyFont.ttf");
}
```

and this my reference

http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/

Comment: Want to change color of tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using [this](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) library (roughike's bottombar) you can try this.

You can set the backgroundcolor of a specific tab by using the following line:

```
bottomBar.getTabAtPosition(0).setBackgroundColor(backgroundColorInt);
```

When you use this line multiple times for each tab, you can change the backgroundcolor of the whole tab.

Answer (score 3):

I've finally achieved to change it with the following code (Xamarin C#)

```
var bottomBarBackground = FindViewById(Resource.Id.bb_bottom_bar_background_view);
bottomBarBackground.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.tabbar_background);
```

tabbar_background.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/YourColor"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Found also here, though the final solution did not work for me with the Xamarin version: [Question about background color](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/205)

Answer (score 1):

Is this the [library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)?

**Other Option:**

seems like you need to set the [Background](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) color a different way:

```
    // Setting colors for different tabs when there's more than three of them.
    // You can set colors for tabs in three different ways as shown below.
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, 0xFF5D4037);
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, "#7B1FA2");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(3, "#FF5252");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(4, "#FF9800");
```

For more inforation:
[Android new Bottom Navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar)

Comment: This the docs? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog

Comment: I use this http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/

Comment: The link you send shows the tutorial, not a Library. The Library is from google. Maybe just use **android:backgroundTint** in your xml.

Answer (score 1):

For all Kotlin fans: To set background color for **all** items in bottom bavigation bar, just add this lines in class MainActivity function onCreate:

```
// finds view in bottom_nav_menu.xml
val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
// sets background color for the whole bar 
navView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourColor))
```