# Xamarin make tabbed layout tabs appear at bottom in android

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin  development. Am doing an apparent for all 3 platforms (android,  io's,  windows).  In a screen I need  to implement tabbedayout with tab buttons to be appeared in bottom (like ios)  for all platforms .  For ios it renders as I expected ,  but in Android the tab buttons are placed to top. Is it possible to make android tab control  buttons to get rendered at the bottom ?

Note- so far,  I have used a simple tabbed layout in xaml page. Havent used any code at platform solutions.

Thanks  in advance

Comment: Tabs-on-top is the Android UI standard.  Ideally you should let each platform obey it's own UI standards unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Agree with Jason on this one, you shouldn't have to alter the experience a user expects from his OS to fit your own needs. There's almost always a way to design it differently and in a way befitting the platform from my experience.

Comment: Bottom tabs are documented in the [Google Material Design documentation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android new Bottom Navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar)

Comment: Xamarin Forms follows the conventions of the platform, that's why the tabs are on top on Android and on Bottom on iOS. If you really need to heavily customize the UI for a specific platform, Xamarin Forms may not be the best UI SDK for you to use. But I agree with Jason and Steve, If I were solely an Android user and in 99% of my apps the tabs are on top, but then I open yours and the tabs are on the bottom, that might be a bit confusing.