# How can I start multiple fragments when starting app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have four fragments, each of them have a TextView.

1. I want to start all fragments and setText for the TextView of each fragment (The activity will only show one fragment at a time).
2. Switch between fragment without deleting it.
   I've tried to setText but it give null pointer exception if I don't show the fragment.

I use BottomBar to switch between fragments.
I'm new with android and my English skill is bad. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

As described in the documentation ([and an example from Google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)):

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment
>   that is persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user
>   can return to the page.
>
> This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of
>   typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of
>   tabs. The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in
>   memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible.
>   This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment
>   instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state. For larger sets
>   of pages, consider FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Beware that depending on how many tabs your bottom bar contains, your activity could be taking a lot of memory ;)

A very complete [guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) from codepath could also help you a lot:

- Define Fragments
- Setup FragmentPagerAdapter
- Apply the Adapter
- Selecting or Getting the Page
- Setup OnPageChangeListener

All of these topics are explained with an example there.

About the BottomBar you have a really good example [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar)

Hope it helps! =)

Comment: Work like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a **`ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter`** [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Try below code for changing fragment on button click

```
 Button buttonNext= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);//button in Bottombar
            buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    vPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);

                }
            });
```

for more about [viewpager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)