# How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?

Tags: android, android-support-design, bottomnavigationview

BottomNavigationView doesn't show menu's title that are inactive.

How to show titles of all menu elements in bottomNavigationBar? 
The problem is that in my case shown only title of element that is clicked.

[image]

Comment: Here's an useful answer if you want to **completely** remove any animation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51052247/2352699

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Implementation of `BottomNavigationView` has condition: when there is more than 3 items then use shift mode.

At this moment you cannot change it through existing API and the only way to disable shift mode is to use reflection.

You'll need helper class:

```java
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And then apply `disableShiftMode` method on your `BottomNavigationView`, but remember if you are inflating menu view from your code, you have to execute it after inflating.

Example usage:

```java
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

PS.

Remember, you'll need to execute this method each time you change menu items in your `BottomNavigationView`.

**UPDATE**

You also need to update proguard configuration file (e.g. proguard-rules.pro), code above uses reflection and won't work if proguard obfuscate the `mShiftingMode` field.

```java
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView { 
    boolean mShiftingMode; 
}
```

Thanks Muhammad Alfaifi for pointing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode/40189977?noredirect=1#comment69921218_40189977) and [providing snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode/40189977?noredirect=1#comment69922205_40189977).

**UPDATE 2**

As Jolanda Verhoef pointed out the new Support library (`28.0.0-alpha1`) and also the new [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) (`1.0.0-beta01`) offers a public property which can be used to manipulate the shifting mode over 3 menu items.

```java
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    ... 
/>
```

In Material Components library it also applies if there are 5 menu items.

**UPDATE 3**

As @ThomasSunderland also pointed out, you can set this property to false `app:itemHorizontalTranslation="false"` without `Enabled` postfix to disable shifting animation.

you can check the full guide to styling the BottomNavigation [here](https://mikescamell.com/bottoms-up-bottomnavigationview-updates-in-the-material-design-design-support-library/index.html)

Comment: The field will be obfuscated so no way to change its value unless you exclude it in your proguard-rules file

Comment: Good catch! I will later update the answer with sample proguard configuration.

Comment: -keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView {
   boolean mShiftingMode;
}

Comment: Just complementing this answer, as I had some doubts first impression: You can replace Timber by Log (pretty obvious) and proguard is file, named proguard-rules.pro, which you just need to add the code below update. Sync build.gradle and it's ready to go. Thanks @PrzemysławPiechota.kibao and MuhammadAlfaifi

Comment: Sometimes, I really wonder why Google forces it's view implementations on developers. While there are 4 options on the Google+ app itself, this simple feature should have been accessible via a simple function if available! Similar issue was there with the TabLayout which was fixed a lot later in support library. Thanks for that workaround to Original Replier and @MuhammadAlfaifi for improving this.

Comment: it works perfectly!! I wish that the `BottomNavigationView` had the option to toggle it without the need for reflection

Comment: Hopefully google will soon release [this version](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.java) of the BottomNavigationView which includes a method to setShiftingMode both in xml and java.

Comment: Have in mind that if you fast click through the tabs the font or icon color will change

Comment: @MuhammadAlfaifi Great stuff. The proguard was causing the problem in upgrade scenario which got fixed by the rules.

Comment: @PrzemysławPiechota.kibao, it's not gonna work on Android P, isn't it? https://developer.android.com/preview/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces.html

Comment: @Yazazzello It should work on Android P, because the BottomNavigationView is from support library, not from Android SDK. Restrictions will be on non-SDK interfaces from packages listed at https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

Comment: The new support library (28.0.0-alpha1) supports changing this behavior through app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"

Comment: The comment of Jolanda Verhoef should be included in the answer as Android P has marked this as a private API and the reflection method does not work anymore.

Comment: For me, I had to following to make it work. 

        val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById < BottomNavigationView >(R.id.navigation)
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView)

Comment: In addition to Jolanda Verhoef, when you use 5 icons the shifting occurs again. But now there is a method called setItemHorizontalTranslationEnabled. Setting this to false keep the icons in their place.

Comment: The setItemHorizontalTranslationEnabled() method can be set in xml with the property app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false" if you want to disable the shifting animation

Comment: 28.0.0 support library changed shifting behavior. You can set this style on your BottomNavigationView if you’d like a bottom navigation bar with the old behavior. style="@style/Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView"

Comment: I can't edit your answer, but FYI: library 28.0.1-alpha1 doesn't exist. Use 28.0.0-alpha1 to use labelVisibilityMode.

Comment: @ThomasSunderland you might want to change it to `app:itemHorizontalTranslation="false"` for 28.0.0-alpha1, so you can use `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` as well combined with proguard configuration to keep the variable name. References here: https://mikescamell.com/bottoms-up-bottomnavigationview-updates-in-the-material-design-design-support-library/index.html

Answer (score 56):

Since support library **28.0.0-alpha1:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
```

Comment: I am using this support library version but still getting error on "labelVisibilityMode" not found.

Comment: Working properly. No need to go for reflection. Thanks a ton

Comment: @Riser make sure you are using `app:` not `android:`

Answer (score 30):

To disable the text animation you can also use this in your dimens.xml file:

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size">12sp</dimen>
```

You might also need to add this in your manifest :

```
tools:override="true"
```

Comment: not working. I believe I had to just add this in /values/dimens.xml ?

Comment: @RohanKandwal need to add `tools:override="true"`

Comment: @Boy Thanks, will try it.

Comment: only change the text size.

Comment: I just need to put like this on my dimens.xml file: `<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:ignore="PrivateResource">12sp</dimen>`

Answer (score 24):

You can now use `app:labelVisibilityMode="[labeled, unlabeled, selected, auto]"` in `28-alpha`

- **`labeled`** will keep all labels visible.
- **`unlabeled`** will show only icons.
- **`selected`** will only show the label for the selected item and shift items.
- **`auto`** will choose labeled or selected based on the number of items you have. labeled for 1-3 items and selected for 3+ items.

Comment: thanks Lunkie! This is the best and easiest solution for me

Comment: Where to add this line of code. I tried to add but there is an error not found.

Comment: @Abdulwahid you can add this in the xml of the bottom navigation bar once you have support library 28 or higher

Comment: @Lunkie thanks now it is clear once support library 28

Answer (score 17):

Przemysław's answer in Kotlin as an extension function

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
fun BottomNavigationView.disableShiftMode() {
    val menuView = getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView
    try {
        val shiftingMode = menuView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode")
        shiftingMode.isAccessible = true
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false)
        shiftingMode.isAccessible = false
        for (i in 0 until menuView.childCount) {
            val item = menuView.getChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView
            item.setShiftingMode(false)
            // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
            item.setChecked(item.itemData.isChecked)
        }
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get shift mode field", e)
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to change value of shift mode", e)
    }
}
```

Usage (with Kotlin Android Extensions):

```
bottom_navigation_view.disableShiftMode()
```

Comment: Working for kotlin. why we need to use this annotation @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") can you explain pls?

Answer (score 12):

To disable the text animation and decrease font size use this in your dimens.xml file:

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size">10sp</dimen> 
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size">10sp</dimen>
```

Comment: One can `Navigate` -> `File...` > `design_bottom_navigation_item.xml` to see that there's no other way.

Answer (score 11):

Works for me

```
bottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
```

or

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
```

Comment: mine was working just fine till target=27 but from target=28, it's broken, text no longer shown. But setLabelVisibilityMode does the trick for me, now works like a charm

Comment: @UgArOFF the question is for disabling shift mode, not about how to enable labels!

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE

in Android sdk version 28 and above they have changed **`item.setShiftingMode(false)`** to **`item.setShifting(false)`**

Also they removed the field **`mShiftingMode`**

So usage will be

```
 BottomNavigationHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNav);
 bottomNav.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);


 private static final class BottomNavigationHelper {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    static void removeShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            item.setShifting(false);
            item.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);

            // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use this code below.
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    fun removeShiftMode(view: BottomNavigationView) {
        val menuView = view.getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView
        menuView.labelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED
        menuView.buildMenuView()
    }

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, since **support library 28.0.0-alpha1** it is possible:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
```

or you can set it [programatically](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setlabelvisibilitymode).

*Note: if you are upgrading from an older version of support library, do not forget to raise compile SDK version.
Check versions of support libraray here: [Support Library versions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions)*

However, you may still get **labelVisibilityMode not found** message when compile, if your app depends on older versions of the design support library. If this is the case, try to upgrade to a version of the given dependency, that depends on at least the version of 28.0.0-alpha1 of design support library. If that's not possible, define the dependency explicitly.

**If you use Gradle**

1. You can check your depdendecies by
   running *dependencies* task and search for the version number of *com.android.support:design*.
2. To add design support dependency explicitly  in your **build.gradle**:

   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Answer (score 5):

For updated answer using the default. Update to latest design library

> implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"

and put to your BottomNavigationView xml attributes

```
app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
```

you can put it also as programmatically

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemHorizontalTranslationEnabled(false);
```

You can find source here [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What does this different from `app:labelVisibilityMode`?

Comment: @wonsuc this is about the animation of icon and text the selected item is animating. While labelVisibilityMode is for displaying whether you want to show icon with text, or just icon to be displayed when selected.

Answer (score 3):

To your **`BottomNavigationView`** add `app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        app:menu="@menu/bn_menu"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

which results in the following

[image: Android Bottom Navigation View Disable Text and Shift]

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, Just add a property in BottomNaviationView

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had some weird behavior with BottomNavigationView. When I was selecting any item/fragment in it, the fragment pushes BottomNavigationView a bit lower, so text of BottomNavigationView goes below the screen, so only icons were visible and text goes hidden on clicking of any item.

If you are facing that weird behavior then Here is the solution.
Just remove

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in your root layout of fragment. Just remove this and boom! BottomNavigationView will work fine, now it can be shown with text and icon. 
I had this in my root CoordinatorLayout of fragment.

Also don't forget to add

```
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

in your activity to disable shifting mode.
Though it is not exactly related to the asked question, but still I find this helpful.

Comment: @abbath0767 have you seen [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47407229/8874958) this? Might be helpful for you.

Comment: I thought I had already tried everything, thank you very much, did not expect to directly find the answer I was seeking for.

Comment: Pleasure @BekaBot

Answer (score 2):

This is a third party library I use and it has many customization options like disabling shift mode, showing only icons, setting icons size, etc.
[BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx)

Answer (score 2):

## To completely remove animations:

If you also want to get rid of that annoying little top margin animation, you need more reflection code. Here's the complete solution that removes any animation:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            item.setShiftingMode(false);

            Field shiftAmount = item.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftAmount");
            shiftAmount.setAccessible(true);
            shiftAmount.setInt(item, 0);
            shiftAmount.setAccessible(false);

            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Unable to get fields");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Unable to change values");
    }
}
```

And make sure to add that to your proguard configuration file:

```
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView { 
    boolean mShiftingMode; 
}
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView { 
    int mShiftAmount;
}
```

Comment: Android 9 (API level 28) introduces new restrictions on the use of non-SDK interfaces and this would not work if targeting 28.  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Answer (score 2):

update your support library to 28.0.0.

```
bottomNav.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using support:design:28.0.0 add this line  app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" to your BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 1):

I use Android Studio 4.0.1 to develop it.
The following is my result...
[image]

About BottomNavigationViewHelper.java
My code is work here

```
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.LabelVisibilityMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShifting(false);
                item.setLabelVisibilityMode( LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can start to use BottomNavigationViewHelper class
And this is my code for MainActivity.java.

BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
**BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navView);**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navView);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_settings,
                R.id.navigation_connection,
                R.id.navigation_status,
                R.id.navigation_report,
                R.id.navigation_profile
        ).build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you even read previously posted answers before posting new ones or just post them? This answer was already posted in this question.

Answer (score 0):

just want to add that above this method disableShiftMode add below code too.
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")

Answer (score 0):

https://android.jlelse.eu/disable-shift-label-animation-from-bottom-navigation-android-b42a25dcbffc

1

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
...
app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"/>
```

2

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
...
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

3

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size"
    tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this for  showing both text and icons on BottomNevigationView for 3 to 5 items and stop shifting.

```
 app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

But you will will face a problem of long text cutting on BottmNevigationView for 5 items. for that ,I found a good solutions for stop shifting of text as well as icons of BottomNevigationView. You can also stop shifting of text as well as Icons on BottomNevigationView also. Snipshots of code is given here.

**1. Add this some line of code in BottomNevigationView as shown**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/seventy_dp"
    android:layout_semitransparent="true"
    android:background="@color/colorBottomNev"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

**2. Add Menu Items like as follows:-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_catalogue"
        android:icon="@drawable/catalogue"
        android:title="@string/catalogue"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contracts"
        android:icon="@drawable/contract"
        android:title="@string/contracts"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_prospects"
        android:icon="@drawable/prospect"
        android:title="@string/prospects"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_performance"
        android:icon="@drawable/performance"
        android:title="@string/performance"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_advance"
        android:icon="@drawable/advance"
        android:title="@string/advance"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

**3.Add this style in style.xml  file:**

```
 <style name="BottomNavigationViewTextStyle">
            <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montmedium</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
            <item name="android:duplicateParentState">true</item>
            <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
            <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        </style>
```

**4)Add these in Dimen folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">10sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I got help from these  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView) and [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/139) .You can also get get help by studying these links.This helps me a lot.Hope this also help you. Thanks....