# BottomNavigationView display both icons and text labels at all times

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design, bottomnavigationview

I am using android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView from design support library version 25

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
        android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="true"/>
```

When there are only three actions in @menu/bottom_navigation_main, it displays both icons and text labels at all times.

What is the way to display both icons and text labels at all the time when there are more than three actions.

Comment: In your bottom_navigation_main.xml menu, if you have android:showAsAction="ifRoom" change it to android:showAsAction="always" for each item.

Comment: No, it didn't work. i had tried it before.

Comment: Can you show your menu xml file

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode)

Comment: place app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" in BottomNavigationView.

Comment: labelVisibilityMode did the trick for me!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 499, accepted):

For anyone still looking for a solution and doesn't want to rely on third party libraries or runtime reflection, BottomNavigationView in Support Library 28/Jetpack natively supports always having text label.

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setlabelvisibilitymode) is the method you're looking for.

Or in XML, `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"`

Comment: which library version do I need?

Comment: support library 28-alpha1+

Comment: You can also change the visibility mode to "auto" in order to show icon-text when pressed/focused only. 

Code: app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"

Comment: You are the man! Thank you this works with latest version of Material Library.

Comment: Works for androix library also

Answer (score 90):

**UPDATE FROM May 8, 2018**

You can use
`app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` 
directly in `<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView />`

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/LabelVisibilityMode

Don't need this below lengthy solution.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

I had some weird behavior with BottomNavigationView. When I was selecting any item/fragment in it, the fragment pushes BottomNavigationView a bit lower, so text of BottomNavigationView goes below the screen, so only icons were visible and text goes hidden on clicking of any item.

If you are facing that weird behavior then Here is the solution.
Just remove

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in your root layout of fragment. Just remove this and boom! BottomNavigationView will work fine, now it can be shown with text and icon. 
I had this in my root CoordinatorLayout of fragment.

Also don't forget to add

```
BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

in your activity to disable shifting mode.

Here is that class:

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public static void removeShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        //this will remove shift mode for bottom navigation view
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR NO SUCH FIELD", "Unable to get shift mode field");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR ILLEGAL ALG", "Unable to change value of shift mode");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This in combination with STAR_ZERO's answer solved my issue!

Comment: In the call you have `disableShiftMode`, and in the class `removeShiftMode`. Apart from that little discrepancy your answer solved the issue for me. I now have five menuitems without shifting and with text+icon. Thank you **very** much!

Comment: Perfect. When you have more than 3 items in your bottom navigation than, there appears a shifting mode. Using this, you can disable that shifting and hence all the icons with text appears at once.

Answer (score 19):

It is difficult in version 25.

Try this code. But I think it's not good solution.

```java
BottomNavigationView navigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
    itemView.setShiftingMode(false);
    itemView.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: In Android Studio, should add code like this:
```
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            itemView.setShiftingMode(false);
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            itemView.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: it is still shifts items

Comment: Perfect !! displays both icon and text. But shifting mode (false) not working.

Comment: This in combination with KishanSolanki124's answer solved my issue!

Answer (score 18):

You can use this for showing both text and icons on BottomNevigationView

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

If you are using this you will be able to view both icon and text

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

> You can use app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" directly in

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_navi"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_managment" />
```

Answer (score 11):

Are you want to this effect ?

[image: Click here to view the image]

[image]

If so, I recommended you to try [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx)。

Comment: Your library is good and impressive work
But i was looking to achieve this functionality using design library 25.0.0
Unfortunately it is against the android design practice

Comment: This is not against Material Design specs, according to the "Fixed bottom navigation bar" in [the docs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html). Also, my personal thanks for sharing this awesome library.

Comment: This IS against the Material Design specs. If you read the document that you provided, you will see that it explicit says "If there are four or five actions, display inactive views as icons only".

Answer (score 11):

Here's a Kotlin extension function that combines @STAR_ZERO and @KishanSolanki124's solution.

```java
fun BottomNavigationView.disableShiftMode() {
    val menuView = getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView

    menuView.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode").apply {
        isAccessible = true
        setBoolean(menuView, false)
        isAccessible = false
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    for (i in 0 until menuView.childCount) {
        (menuView.getChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView).apply {
            setShiftingMode(false)
            setChecked(false)
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```java
myBottomNavigation.disableShiftMode()
```

Answer (score 5):

in BottomNavigationView class there is a BottomNavigationMenuView field and in BottomNavigationMenuView there is a BottomNavigationItemView[] field, which is the items in the bottom bar.

Say n is the number of items, BottomNavigationMenuView will call BottomNavigationItemView.setShiftingMode(n>3) on each member of the BottomNavigationItemView[] array.  This function decides the behaviour (show title always or only upon selection).

so the way to always show the titles is to try to call this method and you can use reflection to access the private fields.

```
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView= (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);


//  get the private BottomNavigationMenuView field 
        Field f = null;
        try {
            f = bottomNavigationView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mMenuView");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        f.setAccessible(true);
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView=null;
        try {
             menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) f.get(bottomNavigationView); 
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//  get the private BottomNavigationItemView[]  field 
        try {
            f=menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mButtons");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        f.setAccessible(true);
        BottomNavigationItemView[] mButtons=null;
        try {
            mButtons = (BottomNavigationItemView[]) f.get(menuView); 
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for(int i=0;i<mButtons.length;i++){
            mButtons[i].setShiftingMode(false);
            mButtons[i].setChecked(true);
        }
```

Comment: This is very good, just we need to make sure the BottomNavigationMenuView also does not shift. ->
f = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");   f.setAccessible(true);
f.setBoolean(menuView, false);

Answer (score 4):

To show the titles all the way. Try this Kotlin code:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ofree)

    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

    val menuView = navigation.getChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView
    for (i in 0 until menuView.childCount) {
        val itemView = menuView.getChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView
        itemView.setShiftingMode(false)
        itemView.setChecked(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to **BottomNavigationViewEx**:
[BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

The programmatically way to always show the labels

```
navigationView.labelVisibilityMode = NavigationBarView.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED
```