# Android Tab Bar text labels disappear if 4 or 5 items present

Tags: java, android

I have used the bottom navigation template in Android Studio 2.3 and added some extra items. The labels and icons are present if 1-3 items are present on the Tab Bar, but if a fourth is added, the label disappears from all items apart from the currently selected item. Is it possible to switch this behaviour off, so that the text appears even when there are five items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly Google discourages this and makes it kinda hacky and difficult to implement this yourself. It is possible though, check this post out [BottomNavigationView display both icons and text labels at all times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396545/bottomnavigationview-display-both-icons-and-text-labels-at-all-times)

Answer (score 2):

Add this dependency to your module build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Then use as your bottom navigation,

```
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
```

To this view you can add:

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

and the labels will remain visible all the time.

Not sure if for **android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView** it works as well. Let me know