# Remove Animation/Shifting mode from BottomNavigationView android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

i am building an application in which i have a BottomNavigationView. Everything works fine until i get to the Activity.

The Navigation is this:

[image]

The problem is that it has this default animation so it pushes the active element everytime higher than the rest.

Another Example:

[image]

So my question is how to get rid of this default animation and every item is aligned when i switch between them?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupBottomBar();
    }

    private void setupBottomBar() {
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragment = new CardDeckFragment();
        transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment).commit();
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_card_deck:{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Card Deck Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fragment = new CardDeckFragment();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.action_favorites:{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Favorites Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fragment = new FavoritesFragment();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.action_favorites_another:{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fragment = new ImageFragment();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.action_profile:{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.action_menu:{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Menu Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fragment = new MenuFragment();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });



    }
}
```

and my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.realtimegaming.androidnative.testproject.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/brown"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing *animateLayoutChanges* and *splitMotionEvents* properties ?

Comment: no...can you give an example?

Comment: Hopefully google will soon release [this version](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.java) of the BottomNavigationView which includes a method to setShiftingMode both in xml and java.

Comment: For those who find this, here is the issue in the Android Support Library issue tracker for adding this as a feature of the BottomNavigationView : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37125827

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544809/7783141

Comment: If you want to **completely** remove animation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51052247/2352699

Comment: In support library 28.0.0 you can use this:

`<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Ok i found a way in case it helps someone else. So by default BottomNavigationView add shiftingmode = true when its more than 3 items.

At this moment you cannot change it through existing API and the only way to disable shift mode is to use reflection.

So we can use this helper to get rid of this:

```
class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

    static void removeShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR NO SUCH FIELD", "Unable to get shift mode field");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR ILLEGAL ALG", "Unable to change value of shift mode");
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem with me!!!

Remember, you'll need to execute this method each time you change menu items in your BottomNavigationView.

**UPDATE**

As per different [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode), you also need to update proguard configuration file (e.g. proguard-rules.pro), code above uses reflection and won't work if proguard obfuscate the mShiftingMode field.

```
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView { 
    boolean mShiftingMode; 
}
```

Comment: It helped! And this is also the right answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this answer helped.. It doesn't take animation out completely.. can still see a small animation but better than the library default behaviour

Comment: God, Android development is crazy...

Comment: Yeah, reflection worked for me. Tried with support library v25.3.1.

Comment: this doesn't work with latest design support library

Comment: Doesn't work for me, too. I'm using support lib 27.0.3.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore - anyone got a solution?

Comment: @ChrisJeon no, it's not. Google wants to maintain consistency by not allowing developers to change the behavior in every other app.

Comment: Working for support library 27.1.1. Thank you!

Comment: In support library 28.0.0-alpha3 `setShiftingMode` is renamed to `setShifting`

Comment: Why the cannot just keep a property for this in xml to acheive this

Comment: In support library 28.0.0 this method is no more. Google wants us to live with this shitty expanding icons here.

Comment: But It's Still Shifting minor.

Comment: it still shifts up a little. as for google, they don't animate it in youtube app. so that's some consistency there for you.

Comment: @LassiKinnunen, in my case it is also shifting up a little, have u got any solutions for that.

Comment: @LAnantaPrasad Sorry, I ended up just doing my bottom navigation by doing a layout for it and then doing the little bit of code necessary to change color of the active one and adding the onclicks on it.

All and all it took way less time and didn't add extra dependencies and it works like I want now. All and all it's not really that much more code and it's easier to change to any animation or behavior now. Had I gone straight to that I would have saved several hours of time. as I had the onNavigationItemSelected I just made the custom code call that, so the change was fairly minimal

Comment: Do add the field -  app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" in bottom navigation view in the XML file. This works with the new design library.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with import ```com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;```