# How to remove icon animation for bottom navigation view in android

Tags: android, animation, icons, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I have implemented Bottom Navigation View from Design Support Library 25 in my project. I have 5 icons in the view. whenever an icon is selected it's having some animation. But when 3 or fewer icons is not showing any animations. I want to remove that animation and need only some color change for the icon. How can I achieve this? Done enough googling, but couldn't find the solution. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176244/how-to-disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode)

Comment: to disable scale animation follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322460/3557894

Answer (score 92, accepted):

got answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033640/1769274).

**To remove animation or shift mode.**

Implementation of `BottomNavigationView` has condition: when there is more than 3 items then use shift mode.

> Create helper class

```
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView; 
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView; 
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView; 
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper { 
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try { 
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi 
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated 
                //noinspection RestrictedApi 
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            } 
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        } 
    } 
}
```

> Usage

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

Comment: hello, thank you for this quetion and ans too, this is working perfect but i'm still struggling with color of icons, my by default icons are black but it shows light black and  when i click the icon it colors turns to white.. how to resolve?

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work in my app :( I've been struggling for hours now

Comment: how can i disable animation which happens when click on item. basically its  a animation thats assign a bottom padding to the icon

Comment: I am getting below error. 

BottomNavigationItemView.setShiftingMode can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

Comment: @SureshParmar, looks like with the latest version of Design Library, this is not working. Any idea if they moved the disable shift mode to the public API?

Comment: for release build [if using proguard] add below line to proguard rules 

-keep class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView { *;}

Comment: For those who find this, here is the issue in the Android Support Library issue tracker for adding this as a feature of the BottomNavigationView : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37125827

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setShiftingMode(boolean)'
UPD: ok. so it's because of android X.
but..
BottomNavigationItemView.setShifting can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.google.android.material) more... (⌘F1)

Comment: I've also experienced the "..can only be called from within the same library group.." error. Specifying a custom textAppearance worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322460/4651172

Answer (score 21):

I tryed this and it worked well

```
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

Or this code mainactivity.xml

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

Comment: or this code in MainActivity.xml                    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"

Comment: it worked for me but there is an issue I have tittle and after implementing this I cant see the title only icons (i have changing icon with tittles)

Answer (score 8):

I just add this code on dimens.xml, and its work like a charm!

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">@dimen/design_bottom_navigation_text_size</dimen>
```

Comment: Best solution so far. Thanks

Comment: Best answer and I've checked multiple ones.

Answer (score 8):

The change in label text size causes the animation.
If you set the general, active and inactive text appearance to be same, there will be no change, hence no animation.

For example :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"

    app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
```

Here, I have set prebuilt style (@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption) but if you want you can set your own text style. just remember to set all three of them to be same.

Answer (score 7):

[BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx) is a good extension to standard BottomNavigationView.
enableShiftingMode(false) does the job for you.

Answer (score 7):

Try this is the layout

`app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"`

or in code level
`mNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);`

And update your design support library to 28.0.+

Answer (score 4):

when i use current version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

and i set labelVisibilityMode to "labeled"

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

under these circumstances, i got it by

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">@dimen/design_bottom_navigation_text_size</dimen>
```

I hope I can help you too.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most elegant or practical solution but you could try to add the following line to your BottomNavigationView.

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

It will remove the label and also disable the animation.

Comment: In order to use this you need to use com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1.

Comment: but i want label with no animation.

Comment: @user7832102 to disable scale animation follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322460/3557894

Answer (score 2):

Just do this..
create dimen file inside values repository and inside the add

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size">10sp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size">10sp</dimen>
```

10sp above is just an example.
And in BottomNavigationView add

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
..
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all these answers and none worked to remove the ripple animation when an icon is clicked.

A solution I found is to use the BottomNavigationViewEx class instead (setup here- https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx).

Then programatically set

```java
bottomNavigationView.setItemRippleColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove animation or shift move create an bottomNavigationViewHelper class using bottomNavigationViewEX

```
package com.example.chitchat.utils;
import android.util.Log;
import com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "bottomNavigationViewHel";

    public static void setupBottomnavigationView(BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomnavigationView: setting up bottom navigation view");

        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableAnimation(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableShiftingMode(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.setTextVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
 
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    .....
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Animation happens because when you tap and icons elevate and label shows, so you just need to remove label

> app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"

Answer (score 0):

You can put a tag inside `BottomNavigationView`:

```
app:itemRippleColor="@color/white"
```

Answer (score -1):

Material Design is getting more handy to use.

App dependency to your Gradle file (Update to the latest version).

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

In MainActivity, just need to call the clearAnimation() function to the BottomNavigationView class

```
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navView.clearAnimation();
```