# Disabling bottom menu animation

Tags: android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649494/how-to-remove-icon-animation-for-bottom-navigation-view-in-android) and all similiar threads, trying to disable the shifting mode on the bottom menu.

Used this helper class:

```
 package com.example.chen.jamsession;

/**
 * Created by chen on 04/05/2017.
 */
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

    static void removeShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR NO SUCH FIELD", "Unable to get shift mode field");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR ILLEGAL ALG", "Unable to change value of shift mode");
        }
    }
}
```

And implemented on my main activity:

```
 BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(navigation);

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

This is my menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_mysessions"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_mysessions" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_user"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_user"
        android:enabled="true"/>




</menu>
```

How do I disable this annoying animation?

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972293/remove-animation-shifting-mode-from-bottomnavigationview-android

Answer (score 1):

If you use gradle 3.x then add this `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` below of `public class BottomNavigationViewHelper`

Here is the full code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

hope this help

Answer (score -2):

```
mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
```

mBottomNavigationView.enableShiftingMode(false);

Comment: very helpful to use a custom class and not showing the method of interest..