# Cannot resolve method 'setShiftingMode(Boolean)' in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview

After upgrading to latest support library '**28.0.0-alpha1**' I cannot disable shifting mode in my `BottomNavigationView` i.e. the `BottomNavigationItemView.setShiftingMode()` method is no longer available.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mShiftingMode in class Landroid/support/design/internal/BottomNavigationMenuView; 
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
    at com.avocure.avocurehealth.utils.ViewUtils.removeNavigationShiftMode(ViewUtils.java:44)
    at com.avocure.avocurehealth.ui.main.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:125)
    at com.avocure.avocurehealth.ui.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I use [this](https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/disable-bottomnavigationview-shift-mode/) method to disable shifting mode.

It would be very much appreciated if anyone could shed some light on whether something has changed in the latest version or is this a bug or something.

Comment: Try this way if you want to remove completely all the animation . https://stackoverflow.com/a/53928761/3448003

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Found the answer**. In support library 28.0.0-alpha1 we can now add labels (remove shifting mode) using any one of the following methods:

**XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        .
        .
        .
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
```

**Code:**

```
mBottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
```

**Or:**

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
public static void removeNavigationShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    menuView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
    menuView.buildMenuView();
}
```