# Bottom Navigation menu text size

Tags: android, xml, menuitem, bottomnavigationview

I have tried this xml code in values/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">30sp</dimen> 
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">30sp</dimen>
```

But still can't change the text size of menu item. If there's any other solution then please do let me know

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52322460/3243275

Comment: gives error when ever i try to run it "Failed Linking reference"

Comment: what is the full error message you are getting?

Comment: the above code dosent give any error but does not work also