# Center bottom navigation bar icons

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-support-design

I'm trying to have **ALL** icons centered, I already disabled the shifting mode by using the following code:

```
/**
 * This is done to remove the shift animation introduced by Android on the bottom navigation view
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/41690461/4243027
 */
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            item.setShiftingMode(false);
            item.setPadding(0,15,0,0);
            // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
            //noinspection RestrictedApi
            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
    }
}
```

And set the title to ""

```
android:title=""
```

I have also tried to do the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/40234361/4243027 but it's not working either.

My bottom navigation view looks like this:

[image: Bottom navigation bar]

I'm using `implementation "com.android.support:design:27.0.1"`

**EDIT:**

As you can see in Layout Inspector, the icon sizes are the same, 63x63 px but the Y of the checked icon is 5 px less.

[image: Layout Inspector]

Comment: Are these not centered? Selected icon base looks a bit higher than the others, but I believe it is due to its different size.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga The checked icon moves a bit to the top, it's not much but you can see the effect, all icon sizes are the same in drawables.

Comment: Then it is due to its size. Are they svg icons? If so, you can try adjusting their sizes.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Yes, they are SVG icons, but all sizes are the same 24x24 dp.

Comment: The difference is in paths' sizes then. Try increasing the size of smaller icons.

Comment: When checking Layout Inspector I can see that non-checekd icons ara at y = 31 and checked icon is at y = 36

Comment: Instead of disabling shifting mode, try adding this line to xml:
app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
If it does not work, try increasing the svg sizes of smaller icons.

Comment: As you can see in the layout inspector image added the sizes of the icons are the same but the checked one is not centered in the bar. Also the line you're suggesting is not available in my support design version.

Answer (score 5):

As of Design Support Library 28.0.0-alpha1 you can use the property

app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"