# Integrating Bottom Navigation with 5 Menu Items

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I was trying to add 5 items to the bottom navigation view , But when i add icons the view get collapse . each icon doesn't get ideal width which means the same width  . please refer to the image , Any reason for this ?
[image]

Edited :- This seems like the default behaviour, If i press on something the button gets the focus

[image]

But is it possible to show it like iOS which means each tab having the same width ?

Comment: The current tab gets enlarged?

Comment: actually this seems to be  the default behaviour, But how can each tab icon should have same width ?

Comment: Don't think you can without creating your own custom bottom menu view

Comment: Best I can think of is maybe if you set it to unselected (setChecked(false))? But then it won't be highlighted..

Comment: To make separation like IOS you should better go with `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom navigation [material design specs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html) there is a section describing ["fixed" vs "shifting" modes](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs)

While this doesn't appear in the official [bottom navigation view documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) (ahem google), if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.java) you will see that there is the ability to set the "Shifting Mode" both via [xml](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.java#L206) and [java](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.java#L411).

Please note that I haven't tried this and am basing it on the source code alone.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i tried to search the source but its not available using 26 version

Comment: but i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972293/remove-animation-shifting-mode-from-bottomnavigationview-android